# atmel studio AVR debugger quickwatch crazy (float)(1000 / 100)= 1092616192 float

Tags: avr-gcc, atmelstudio

In Atmelstudio 6.1 I debug my AVR 328
When opening Quickwatch I tried to analyze a problem and due to unexected problems I stripped down the problem to this:
Entered expression is (float)(1000), also tried with .0F

```
(float)(1000)   1148846080  float
(float)(1000.0F)    1148846080  float
```

What the heck is going wrong ?

Comment: aww damn it, a bug in Atmel studio. How can they have SUCH a bug.
Their debugger does not understand float and displays it as decimal unsigned 32.
 open Project|Properties|Advanced, change the 'Use
GDB flag'

Comment: `1148846080` = `0x447a0000` = `1000.0f`

Comment: yep but in float presentation it has to show 1000.0f and not the binary value. It is a bug in 6.1 and 6.2 of Atmel Studio and solved by my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

This was a known bug in 6.1 and some of the 6.2 versions (fixed at least in the latest SP of 6.2). The number is the integer representation of the IEEE floating point number (showing the mantissa and exponent bitfields as a int).